# python flask scheduling: all workers start scheduler task

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I use scheduled tasks inside a flask application:

```
    import time
    import atexit

    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


    def intervall():
        with app.app_context():
            call_function_to_do()

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func=intervall, trigger="interval", seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()

    # Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
    atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

My problem is that all gunicorn workers are starting the scheduler task. In this case checking for a timeout situation and sending an email to a user.

Does anybody have an idea how to only have one worker excute `call_function_to_do()` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options. One of them outlined in the [FAQ](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes) is to separate scheduler into separate process and communicate with the process using some remote access protocol (e.g. using [RPyC](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). The other method is to start the scheduler in Flask app, but ensure that only one such instance is run. You can use some kind of locking mechanism, e.g. [RedLock](https://github.com/glasslion/redlock).